# What is the physical reason for temperature decreasing with energy addition for Mach numbers between 1 and 1/root gamma?

Tags: flow

I am currently learning about 1D compressible flow properties, and the equations governing them, but I don't understand the physical nature of it properly, I only really have the equations as a starting point. What I do know is this: If you add energy to a 1D flow, you get a relationship for the temperature which looks like this:

$$
\frac{dT}{T}=\frac{\left(1-1.4M^{2}\right)}{1-M^{2}}\frac{dH}{c_{p}T}
$$

Where dH is the change in heat over the flow "slice" under consideration. If you normalize the change in temperature by dividing the leftmost fraction (the one with dH in the numerator) then you can see how the change in temperature changes with the Mach number, or:

$$
\frac{c_{p}dT}{dH}=\frac{\left(1-1.4M^{2}\right)}{1-M^{2}}
$$

Which results in a plot that looks like this:

https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipPfg6Lb0tuK8BU6fwXvdrJqZTuee8IuChs_no2U/photo/AF1QipNoyC551Y01eGerzuXuZKiYGvQL7V6fVusbi9vX

My question is if anyone here knows a more physical explanation for why the temperature starts to decrease between that narrow Mach number range of 1/sqrt(gamma) and 1. I've been looking through the other flow equations but can't seen to find an intuitive relationship. Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately the image link is a 404 (for me anyway)

Comment: @Frog: for me as well

Comment: I suppose physics.se might also have an answer

Comment: Can you source those equations please?